How does the on/off switch prevent sound from playing on the Retro Radio?
I'm aware that the Retro Radio (10334) uses a sound brick to produce sound:

This brick produces a random sound when its single button is pressed. The right dial on the radio interacts with the brick to produce sound.

However, the on/off dial on the left prevents sounds from being produced when the right dial is turned. How is this accomplished?

This is accomplished by making use of a few key elements commonly used in transmissions within Technic vehicles. Here's an overview of the internal mechanics from the instructions:

The dial on the right turns a worm gear moving the needle indicating the radio frequency. The orange wheel circled on the left will engage the button on the sound element when rotated. The dial on the left (the on/off switch) controls whether or not these two mechanisms are connected.
Four key Technic elements are used here:

42195 Technic Driving Ring Connector Smooth



18946 Technic Gear 16 Tooth with Clutch on Both Sides



18947 Technic Driving Ring 3L



35188 Gear Shifter


When combined, these elements provide a way to build mechanisms that engage or disengage certain gears. In this set, they are placed underneath the on/off dial:

The orange shifter is then connected to the dial to allow the sound brick to be engaged or disengaged from the frequency slider mechanism:

In this way, the right dial will always move the frequency indicator, but it will produce sound if and only if the left dial is in the "on" position.
